# How to calculate the LineHeight of the first line of a CKEditor instance?

Tags: javascript, css, html, ckeditor

Title. I've been looking around for a while in Google for this but I only found a plugin that sets the LineHeight (https://ckeditor.com/addon/lineheight), and doesn't seem to allow to calculate it.

Is it possible? How would I calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This addon use line-height css property, which can be specified in %

e.g. you can try
`config.line_height="10%;20%;30%" ;`

If it's not solved your problem, can you clarify, please, - calculate line-height based on that and what describe please "the first line" ?

**UPDATE:**

`var firstElement = CKEDITOR.instances["textarea"].document.getBody().getFirst();
var firstLineHeight = firstElement.$.offsetHeight;`

Comment: The first line is the first line of the CKEditor instance. I want to calculate the height (in pixels) of that line.

Comment: @Polygons, i updated my answer, please check if it work for you